# SSMS Join Not Appending

Tags: sql

I am trying to do a simple join and it's not working. Below is my code with test data.  Instead of joining them together it adds them to the bottom.  Any help would be appreciated.  I tried doing it all in one join and select but can't get it to work so I'm trying to break it down.

```
    CREATE TABLE #inkoff
    ( 
            InvoiceDate varchar(50)
        ,   JobNumber varchar(50)
        ,   EstNum varchar(50)
        ,   Estimate varchar(50)
        ,   Actual varchar(50)
    )
    --This is an insert into select, but for testing purposes:
    INSERT INTO #inkoff (InvoiceDate, JobNumber, EstNum)
                        VALUES (20170101, '0001', 'E0001')
    INSERT INTO #inkoff (InvoiceDate, JobNumber, EstNum)
                        VALUES (20170201, '0002', 'E0002')
    INSERT INTO #inkoff (InvoiceDate, JobNumber, EstNum)
                        VALUES (20170301, '0003', 'E0003')
    INSERT INTO #inkoff (InvoiceDate, JobNumber, EstNum)
                        VALUES (20170401, '0004', 'E0004')
    --SELECT * FROM #inkoff
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
CREATE TABLE #inkest
    ( 
            EstNum varchar(50)
        ,   Estimate varchar(50)
    )
    --This is another insert into select but it is SELECT Distinct (EstimateNumber), Sum (Cost) as Estimate
    INSERT INTO #inkest (EstNum, Estimate)
        VALUES ('E0001', '100.25')
    INSERT INTO #inkest (EstNum, Estimate)
        VALUES ('E0002', '55.25')
    INSERT INTO #inkest (EstNum, Estimate)
        VALUES ('E0003', '75.26')
    INSERT INTO #inkest (EstNum, Estimate)
        VALUES ('E0004', '75.26')
    INSERT INTO #inkest (EstNum, Estimate)
        VALUES ('E0005', '100.01')                  
 --SELECT * FROM #inkest

 --Instead of appending them to the first four rows, it adds 5 rows to the bottom and doesn't join them up. 
 INSERT INTO #inkoff (Estimate) 
        SELECT A.Estimate FROM #inkest A 
        LEFT JOIN #inkoff  B    
        ON A.EstNum = B.EstNum 

SELECT * FROM #inkoff
SELECT * FROM #inkest
```

Comment: you should look into `UPDATE`

Comment: Have you check the documentation of what `INSERT` does?  It insert new record into table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you're wanting to do is an `update` rather than an insert, similar to this:

```
    update b
    set b.estimate = a.estimate
    from #inkest a left join #inkoff b on a.EstNum=b.EstNum
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked.  I don't know why I was trying to do a join. Thanks again.